# Data Source Credentials issue with Excel PowerPivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, passwords, credentials, powerpivot

I am using `Excel 2010` with `PowerPivot`. I am trying to go to the `Query Editor`. When I click on `Table Properties`, I get a password prompt:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know the password and when I press `OK`, I get a **User name or password is invalid** error:

[image]

I've never had this issue before. The problem started to occur when performing those steps via different computers than the one the spreadsheet was initially created with. Unfortunately I can't open the spreadsheet with the original computer as it went missing.

**Is there a way to bypass the Data Source Credentials (I've never had to enter any before)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, problem wasn't related to credentials but to data path. After acknowledging the error message, you get another error at the bottom of the table properties window:

[image]

That's what made me realize it could be related to data paths. When clicking on `Existing Connections` I realized files were mapped under a different drive. Creating that drive on the new computer fixed the issue.